# Problema al arrastrar un GameObject con RectTransform en Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, drag-and-drop

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de **Unity** donde tengo un mapa de juego en un **entorno 2D**.

El mapa está compuesto por varios `GameObjects` que forman el fondo y están contenidos dentro de un `Canvas`. Estoy intentando implementar una funcionalidad que permita a los usuarios arrastrar el fondo para explorar diferentes áreas del mapa.

Sin embargo, estoy enfrentando un problema: cuando comienzo a arrastrar el fondo, la esquina inferior izquierda del `Canvas` se alinea con la esquina inferior izquierda de la pantalla, y el fondo se bloquea en esa posición, sin permitir más movimientos.

La estructura de mis `GameObjects` es la siguiente:

- `Canvas` (Padre de `CampaingMap`)
- `CampaingMap` (`empty game object`, Padre de `Background`)
- `Background` (con el script `DragHandler` y padre de los demás `gameobjects`)
- `BackgroundEstellar`, `BackgroundPurple`, Otros botones y elementos de ui.

He implementado el arrastre usando los interfaces `IDragHandler` y `IBeginDragHandler` de **Unity**. Aquí está el código que estoy utilizando:

```
public class DragBackground : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    private Vector2 originalLocalPointerPosition;
    private Vector3 originalPanelLocalPosition;
    private RectTransform panelRectTransform;
    private RectTransform parentRectTransform;

    void Awake()
    {
        panelRectTransform = transform as RectTransform;
        parentRectTransform = panelRectTransform.parent as RectTransform;
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData data)
    {
        if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(parentRectTransform, data.position, data.pressEventCamera, out originalLocalPointerPosition))
        {
            originalPanelLocalPosition = panelRectTransform.localPosition;
        }
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
    {
         if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(parentRectTransform, data.position, data.pressEventCamera, out Vector2 localPointerPosition))
    {
        Vector3 offsetToOriginal = localPointerPosition - originalLocalPointerPosition;
        panelRectTransform.localPosition = originalPanelLocalPosition + offsetToOriginal;
    }
    }


    Vector3 ClampToWindow(Vector3 position)
    {
        Vector3 result = position;

        Vector3 minPosition = parentRectTransform.rect.min - panelRectTransform.rect.min;
        Vector3 maxPosition = parentRectTransform.rect.max - panelRectTransform.rect.max;

        result.x = Mathf.Clamp(position.x, minPosition.x, maxPosition.x);
        result.y = Mathf.Clamp(position.y, minPosition.y, maxPosition.y);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: El Canvas es para la interfaz. Tal vez te estés confundiendo y lo quieras utilizar para otra cosa. Para juegos 2D es conveniente usar sprites como GameObject normales, con Transform, no RectTransform.